# Why am I getting Not Found Error in MERN Stack

Tags: http-status-code-404, mern

i am having a problem connecting to backend
whenever i click submit button, i am getting a 404 error. clicking submit button must redirect to localhost:5000/posts
i am getting the error from 3 sites from my client side:

1. https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/posts-mern-stack/blob/master/client/src/api/index.js#L5
2. https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/posts-mern-stack/blob/master/client/src/actions/posts.js#L17
3. https://github.com/Yokubjon-J/posts-mern-stack/blob/master/client/src/components/Form/Form.js#L17

any suggestions?
i even included proxy in package.json file but it wasn't helpful
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the help from online community, I realized that the mistake was in `server/routers/post.js` file where i typed `router.get('/', createPost);`, i changed it to `router.post('/', createPost);` and my problem was solved by it.

A helpful comment by a member of online community:

If you get 404 with an endpoint that should exists, usually it means you've either used the wrong method - eg get instead of post - or you haven't connected your router to your app. (If other end points work for the router then it's unlikely the latter.)